# Insert (internally existing) column headers as first row to a table

Tags: sas

Assume that we have a table `INPUT_TABLE` which has four columns `name`, `lat`, `lon`, and `z`, filled with many data sets. In the **SAS Explorer** it would e.g. look like this:

```
   name    lat        lon        z 
1  Germany 49.420469  8.7269178  17
2  England 51.5540693 -0.8249039 16
...
```

I handover a `PREPROCESSED_TABLE` based on this `INPUT_TABLE` to a macro `%tabl`:

```
data V42.PREPROCESSED_TABLE;
   set V21.INPUT_TABLE;
   drop NAME;
run;

%tabl(libin=V42, file=PREPROCESSED_TABLE);
```

The macro itself I am not allowed to modify.

Among other things, `%tabl` also writes a plain text file `PREPROCESSED_TABLE.txt`:

```
49.420469|8.7269178|17
51.5540693|-0.8249039|16
```

I would like to have the header names written out as well, e.g.:

```
lat|lon|z
49.420469|8.7269178|17
51.5540693|-0.8249039|16
```

My idea is to expand the `PREPROCESSED_TABLE` somewhere in the `data` step - could somebody help me with that, please? How can I read out the header names which are internally stored?

Comment: To be clear you are passing the macro a string like XXX and it is using that as just part of the file name that it generates?  Does the macro support you passing in the full name of the file in quotes?  Does the macro support you passing in a fileref instead?  Does the macro support you passing in `"PREPROCESSED_TABLE.txt" MOD` so that it can use that in a FILE statement and the MOD operand will cause it to append the data to the existing file instead of creating a new file?

Comment: The macro takes the content of `PREPROCESSED_TABLE` and dumps it into  a file, so I need to insert an additional row as first line. I cannot pass anything except the table content, that is why I have to take the table column headers and write it as new first row.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. You talked about the name of the dataset you want to output. I was asking about the file the macro is creating.  Are you saying the macro always names the output file based on the name of the input dataset?

Comment: Does the macro do anything other than create the pipe delimited file?  If so then just don't use it. Write the pipe delimited file yourself.

Comment: Oh, sorry for not getting your point. The file the macro is creating is(confusingly) called `Preprocessed_table.txt`. For your 2nd question: Yes, the macro does some additional processing steps and outputs additional header and footer, so that I cannot just concatenate the files. But what I can do is to strip away the stuff added by `%tabl` further downstream.

Comment: If you are stripping the extra stuff the macro generates in the file then why not just add a step to write the type of file you want and ignore the file the macro generates? Or use if for something else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given [Reeza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1919583/reeza)'s and [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4965549/tom)'s hints, I figured out a workaround myself: We simple call out macro `%tabl` twice, once with a 1-row-table with column-names and once with the data. This approach essentially corresponds to attaching to the file first the headers and then then data to the file (except that I have to worry about additional things added by `%tabl` further down in the process chain).

The technical difficulty I had was how to extract this 1-row-table with column names from the meta-info of the table input table `V21.INPUT_TABLE`.

My team mate showed me how that is done. To make it testable for everybody, I will show this step for the test data table `sashelp.class`:

```
proc contents data=sashelp.class out=meta (keep=NAME VARNUM) noprint;
run;

proc sort data=meta out=meta2;
by VARNUM;
run;

proc transpose data=meta2 out=colheaders (drop=_NAME_ _LABEL_);
var name;
run;
```

As a result, we will have a table `colheaders` with exactly one line containing the table headers, sorted by `VARNUM` which is the order in which they appear in the original table:

```
   COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4    COL5
1  NAME  SEX   AGE   HEIGHT  WEIGHT
```

Problem solved, at least theoretically.

Comment: Your posted code will sort the variable names alphabetically. You probably want to sort them by VARNUM instead.  If you want to use PROC CONTENTS then keep VARNUM and add a PROC SORT step.

Comment: Pull it from sashelp.vcolumns or dictionary.columns.

Comment: That doesn't explain how you combine the files, so it doesn't actually answer your question posted.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to make a file with one line with the variable names then just write the file yourself.  First get the names into a dataset (in order) and then write them.  For example you could use PROC TRANSPOSE with OBS=0 dataset option to generate a file with one observation per variable.

```
 proc transpose data=V42.PREPROCESSED_TABLE(obs=0) out=NAMES ;
   var _all_ ;
 run;
```

Which you can then use to write to a file.

```
 data _null_;
   set names ;
   file 'preprocessed.txt' dsd dlm='|';
   put _name_ @ ;
 run;
```

If you also want to add the data to that same file just use a second data step. Make sure to use the MOD option on the FILE statement so that data lines are appended to the existing file.

```
data _null_;
  set V42.PREPROCESSED_TABLE;
  file 'preprocessed.txt' dsd dlm='|' mod;
  put (_all_) (+0);
run;
```

If you need to call the existing macro for other reasons you could either ignore the file it creates.  Or if for some reason the content is different than just the simple dump of the file then you could just concatenate the file with the the headers with the file the macro generates.  Say the macro generated 'PREPROCESSED_TABLE.txt' and your code generated the one line file 'headers.txt'.  Then this step will read both and write 'PREPROCESSED_TABLE_w_headers.txt';

```
data _null_;
  file 'PREPROCESSED_TABLE_w_headers.txt';
  if _n_=1 then do;
    infile 'headers.txt';
    input;
    put _infile_;
  end;
  infile 'PREPROCESSED_TABLE.txt';
  input;
  put _infile_;
run;
```